# Bootstrap Modal - Set remote path and open programmatically

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm using bootstrap 3 modals using the remote path option as follows.

```
<a href="mystuff.htm" class="btn btn-default" role="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modCurIssue">view</a>

<div id="modCurIssue" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
   <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
         <!--- content from mystuff.htm will appear here --->
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

This works fine, but instead of clicking the link I want to open the modal programmatically!

I'm trying to avoid triggering a click() event on the link if possible.

Comment: All you need is an iframe. Just create an iframe in your model-content div.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of `3.2.1` the remote option is deprecated and will be removed in future versions. It is advisable to load the content explicitly and then call the `show` method to open the modal:

```
 $('#modCurIssue').find('.modal-content').load( 'mystuff.htm', function() {
     $('#modCurIssue').modal( 'show' );
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the methods section on http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals it's quite easy:

```
$('#modCurIssue').modal('show')
```

Comment: This is true, but it doesn't take in to account the data-target. i.e. loading in the content from remote url.

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="#" class="btn btn-default" role="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modCurIssue">view</a>

<div id="modCurIssue" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
   <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
         <iframe src="mystuff.htm"></iframe>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```